# how to add a buffered image as back ground of JFrame then add a panel on this image?

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jframe

I'm in the second term of Computer engineering .

my problem is how to add JButton etc... on the background image ,you know I have written the below code , please help me to continue:
as I said my JBotton can't be shown on the image and here is the problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyCalcFrame extends JFrame
{
    private BufferedImage myImage;
    private JPanel mypanel;
    private JButton mybtn;

    public MyCalcFrame()
    {
        this.setBounds(410, 110, 600, 450);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);



        try
        {
            this.myImage=ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\1.jpg"));
        }//end try
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Image dose not exist.","NO Image found",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }//end catch
        this.mypanel=new JPanel();
        this.mypanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setContentPane(new ImagePanel(myImage));
        mybtn=new JButton("hello");
        this.getContentPane().add(mybtn);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }//end MyCalcFrame constructor

    class ImagePanel extends JComponent 
    {
        private Image image;

        public ImagePanel(Image image)
        {
            this.image = image;
        }//end constructor
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }//en paintComponent
    }//end ImagePanel
    //################ End constructor ########################
    //public void paint(Graphics g)
    //{
    //  g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, this);
    //}//end method paint

    //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ main @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        new MyCalcFrame();
    }//end method main
    //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ main @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
}//end class MyCalcFrame
```

Comment: An easy way to do this, is to use `JLabel` with a `LayoutManager` as the content pane of your `JFrame`. Check this [answer with a custom component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401109/java-add-background-image-to-frame/13401871#13401871) and [this answer with a `JLabel`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288303/best-example-for-creating-programmatically-splashscreen-with-text/16289376#16289376)

Answer (score 3):

A JComponent doesn't use a Layout Manager so when you add the button it doesn't display.

Try using a `FlowLayout` on your component.

Also, don't use setBounds() for your frame. You should `pack()` and then use `setLocationByPlatform(true)`, so the frame is displayed at its preferred size.

You would need to implement `getPreferredSize()` for your component so this works.

Comment: and a call `super.paintComponent` would be really nice to ;)