# Best way to create splash screen for a Java application?

Tags: java, swing, cross-platform, splash-screen

I have a Java application that is designed to run on both Windows and OSX. In some cases it might take a while to load because it basically looks at the directories inside the main directories (so two levels of directories). When it is done the main GUI will be shown, unless there are any errors, in which case a JOptionPane will appear.

I would like to show a splash screen until either of the GUI or a message is displayed, however I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. Also, I'm not sure how to create the splash screen to start with - is there a program that people use?

Comment: You can take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288303/best-example-for-creating-programmatically-splashscreen-with-text/16289376#16289376) or use the built in of Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to create image and application for that? do you mean that you need something like photoshop?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Thank you for the link to the answer you provided. It looks very helpful - I didn't come across it in my searches.

Comment: @Warlock Yes, I have no experience in creating graphics like this so I didn't know if there was any specific software I could use.

Comment: @Warlock is there anything free?

Comment: @Andy Yes [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On application start show a JOptionPane with image that is your splash screen, meanwhile fire a thread to do the load for you, when its done hide the pane with splash and show your main UI

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is what I thought of doing, however I don't have too much experience with threads, so can the splash screen be launched in a separate thread instead, and what would be the best way to determine when to hide the splash screen?

Comment: You need to do the load on thread to check when does it finish, other way since you have a splash image (not a video) and don't care about UI freezing, you could show splash do the load and hide splash without using threads

Comment: You are right. I've just tried it and I do not need threads because of the nature of everything. Thank you for your help - this was the easiest way

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a Swing application, then there is a Java Tutorial on this subject:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

For JNLP launched Swing applications, this blog covers changing the JNLP splash screen:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/changing_the_java_web_start

I couldn't find a tutorial for SWT applications, but here are a couple of examples:

- https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/svn/peppol/dev/vcd/VCDBuilder/vcd-bootstrap/src/main/java/eu/peppol/vcd/bootstrap/SplashScreen.java
- http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet104.java

---

If you are asking about how to create the graphics / images for your splash screen, there are many tools out there for creating images, and recommending one would be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did see the Java Tutorial but it seemed a bit vague and I wasn't sure when the splash screen would disappear. But those examples should be helpful.

Comment: In the first tutorial, the splash doesn't disappear spontaneously.  You need to call `close()` on the `SplashScreen` object when your app is read for business.

Comment: I've just looked at the full code and you're right. I misunderstood the API a little