# how to open a JProgress bar in a new frame after a button click in a previous frame?

Tags: java, swing, thread-sleep, jprogressbar

This is the function I am implementing in the frame that opens up after clicking the button on a previous frame... The frame for the progress bar opens up easily, but the progress is not shown... please, help me solve this.

```
public void iterate() {
    while (num < 2000) {
        current.setValue(num);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        num += 95;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288303/best-example-for-creating-programmatically-splashscreen-with-text/16289376#16289376)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're doing a long-running bit of code on the Swing event thread, and this will put the Swing event thread, and your entire GUI with it, to sleep.

The solution, do the long running bit of code in a background thread such as is available through a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), either that or use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to advance your number and forgo the while (true) and the `Thread.sleep(...)`.

Also note that your second dependent window should be a dialog such as a JDialog or a JOptionPane, not another JFrame.